# Support Cyrillic data in BigQuery

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-analytics, google-bigquery

Question about BigQuery - its normal work with Cyrillic?

Can i use data with russian name of events or param ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLLrq.png)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use Cyrillic in your data! Try below to see

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'открыли' event, 'Hi Alex Homa. Welcome to Stack Overflow' salute UNION ALL
  SELECT 'закрыли', 'Привет Алексей Хома. Добро пожаловать!' 
)
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE event = 'закрыли'
```

with result

```
Row event   salute   
1   закрыли Привет Алексей Хома. Добро пожаловать!
```

But obviously you cannot use Cyrillic for column / parameters names